# can't assign reducer on typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am following a microsoft tutorial on redux + typescript here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter but somehow on the last part I am stuck:

```
const store = createStore<StoreState, any, any, any>(
  enthusiasm,
  {
    enthusiasmLevel: 1,
    languageName: 'TypeScript'
  },
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

this is the error I am getting along with the screenshot below:

```
Argument of type '(state: StoreState, action: EnthusiasmAction) => StoreState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<StoreState, any>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'StoreState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.ts(2345)
```

[image]

I believe I have followed everyhing and here, I want to add thunk also, but i got error on the argument enthusiasm, and i dont know why, help?

Answer (score 1):

The key part is here:

> ```
> Type 'StoreState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.
>       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreState'.ts(2345)
> ```

It sounds like you need to enable strict null checks ([`--strictNullChecks`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). Without them, basically every type in your code is implicitly `YourType | undefined`, but what you're providing this callback to seems to require a callback that accepts/provides exactly `StoreState`, not `StoreState | undefined`. More on nullable types and strict null checks [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types).

(Or I could have the wrong end of the stick and you *do* have strict null checks enabled, but what you're using expects them *not* to be. But I think I have it the right way around.)